# Merging ZCTA boundaries to get user defined territory based on zip codes in R

Tags: r, subset, geospatial, polygons

I am trying to make a map of sales territory defined by my client to show the annual sales achieved in each of the territory.

I downloaded the ZCTA file from us census [cb_2015_us_zcta510_500k.zip](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html). I used the following code to get the territory map:

```
en`#reading shapefile
oregon <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "cb_2013_us_zcta510_500k")

#alignment data from hive, this is the file that have zip codes corresponding to all the territories
Territory_Zip_dataunique_zip <- dataTier1
Territory_Zip_dataunique_zip$l_alignment.zipcode <- clean.zipcodes(Territory_Zip_dataunique_zip$l_alignment.zipcode)



terrData <- Territory_zip_data_unique_zip

#Get all the zip codes from my territory file
terrData1 <- data.frame(Territory_zip_data_master[,1])
names(terrData1) <- c("GEOID10")

#Subset ZCTA file to have only zips that are in my territory file
oregonSubset <- merge(oregon,terrData1, all.y = F, all.x = F)

#merge with territory file to get corresponsding territory ids
natnds <- merge(oregonSubset, terrData, by.x = "GEOID10", by.y = "l_alignment.zipcode", all.y = F, all.x = F)

#make territory ids as revised ids for polygondataframe
revised_id <- natnds$l_alignment.territoryid

#Redefine shapefile based on revised ids
unionPoly <- unionSpatialPolygons(oregonSubset,revised_id)

#Fortify the spacialpolygondataframe
unionPoly_fort <- fortify(unionPoly)

#Plot
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = ds, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group,
                                  fill = id), color = "black", size = 0.25) +
                                  theme(legend.position="none",
                                        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA),
                                        panel.background =element_rect(fill = "transparent",colour = NA), # or theme_blank()
                                        panel.grid.minor =element_blank(), 
                                        panel.grid.major =element_blank(),
                                        axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
                                        axis.text = element_blank(),
                                        axis.title = element_blank())
```

## I get the following output

[outcome of the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKO91.jpg)

Now, the problem is the gaps(white space in between) on the left side of the chart. How can I get continuous territory boundaries filled with color without those gaps? In other words, can I somehow make it like the right part of the chart?

I understand that it is data issue, and for those gaps there are no zip code defined, I can see that by plotting the original shapefile.

Has anyone tried to bridge those gaps?

Answer (score 0):

First, the fix. Pre-2010 borders, which don't have gaps, are available at https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/prev_cartbndry_names.html.

Now I'll tell you what the gaps mean. The issue, at least in part, is that some US land is not in a declared ZCTA. According to the Census' page, "For the 2010 Census, large water bodies and large unpopulated land areas do not have ZCTAs" (I can't link to, but you'll be able to find it on Google). This is particularly bad in low-population areas, but there are even missing areas near large cities.

See, for example, this exploration around the Chicago area: https://walkerke.shinyapps.io/tigris-zip-income/. The missing areas are clearly things like nature preserves (like Midewin National Tallgrass Prarie and what Google suggests is the Braidwood nature preserve just to its South), which should by definition not have long-term human habitation.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, but the link to pre-2010 ZCTA is dead. Any of the ZCTA files I've tried from census dot gov have resulted in gaps like the above. Any idea where one can find the pre-2010 gap-less ZCTA these days?